# How do I get text from div?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** info from one website, to get information about user, for bot to have stored in a channel.

I've watched tutorials but none worked.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.rubyrealms.com/user/KOMKO190/")
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

How would I get the DIVs and the text from div?

Comment: you should include only the scrapping code (the beautiful soup part) the discord part is unnecessary. The code when you attempt the parsing and face with problem so that we can help you debug the problem you are having. but I think you need to do .text or something when you extracted the div

Comment: Please include only beautifulsoup related code and yeah I also think precisely you just need to do .text as @Hamuel said

Answer (score 1):

I parsed some sample items from the page, that should get you going started:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.rubyrealms.com/user/KOMKO190/")
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

name = soup.select_one('div.profile-title').text.strip()
about = soup.select_one('div.profile-about').text.strip()
achievements = [span['title'] for span in soup.select('div.achievements span[title]')]
stats = [div.text.strip() for div in soup.select('div.stats div')]

print('{: <20}{}'.format('Name:', name))
print('{: <20}{}'.format('About:', about))
print('{: <20}{}'.format('Achievements:', achievements))
print('{: <20}{}'.format('Stats:', stats))
```

Prints:

```
Name:               KOMKO190
About:              Hey! My name is KOMKO190, you maybe know me from the forums or discord. I am a programmer, I know a bit of JavaScript, small portion of C++, Python and html/css. Mostly python. My user ID is 7364. ||| 5th owner of Space Helmet :)
Achievements:       ['Verified', 'Novice Collector', 'XP Prodigy', '1k Forum Posts']
Stats:              ['297 Profile Views', '1826 Forum Posts', 'Last seen 40 mins ago', 'Joined Apr 27, 2019']
```

Comment: Thanks! In meantime I did figure it out but your code obviously looks and works better! There is one problem with discord.py that I need to figure out, but thanks for the code!